# Can't install “qt-examples” and “qt-docs” packages because dependency is too new?

Tags: linux, centos-7, yum, qt, rhel-7

What is wrong with my repository? Why can't I install `qt-examples`? How do I fix the repository?

```
$ sudo yum install qt-examples
[...]
Error: Package: 1:qt-examples-4.8.7-2.el7.x86_64 (base)
           Requires: qt(x86-64) = 1:4.8.7-2.el7
           Installed: 1:qt-4.8.7-3.el7_6.x86_64 (@updates)
               qt(x86-64) = 1:4.8.7-3.el7_6
           Available: 1:qt-4.8.7-2.el7.x86_64 (base)
               qt(x86-64) = 1:4.8.7-2.el7
```

I have a similar problem installing `qt-docs`. I don't want to downgrade Qt. Example code that's slightly outdated should work fine.

Can I force it to install the 7-2 examples? Or, how do I get the 7-3 qt-examples? Machine has no internet access; so package management is super fun.

Answer (score 0):

You have installed `qt-4.8.7-3` from `@updates`, and now `yum` is trying to install `qt-examples` from `base`, so you should re-enable the `update` repository, then installation should run fine.

Although the software would probably run fine with a minor version mismatch, you wouldn't want to risk strange bugs happening due to mismatches...

to be complete:

**yes** you can force the installation, but that is a little more complicatated with `yum`; I don't really know if there is an option therefor, but I'm sure you can do it with `rpm`:

- download your package
- install with `rpm -Ivh --nodeps`